# iOS Spritekit Cannot Run SKAction on a Subclassed SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios7, subclass, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction

For my question I would like a more conceptual answer rather than a code one.

I have a iOS application using Spritekit. I have a class that subclasses a SKSpriteNode, so that I can add additional properties to the node. I am able to successfully create the SKSpriteNode and display it on my SKSpriteNode background and remove it using an action. However, when I run any actions such as:

```
SKAction * moveAction = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(100, 100)   duration: 1];
```

It does not perform the action for my subclass. However, if I apply this same action towards another SKSpriteNode than it performs the action. These are created on a timer that runs every 5 seconds.

Some example code follows:

**MyScene.m:**

```
-(void) timeTest {
     MySubclass * subclassTest = [[MySubclass alloc] initWithImage:@"myImage"];
     SKSpriteNode *test = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"myImage"];
     subclassTest.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);
     test.position = CGPointMake(0, 100);

     [self.background addChild:subclassTest];
     [self.background addChild:test];

     SKAction * moveAction = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(300, 300)   duration: 2];

     [subclassTest runAction: moveAction];
     [test runAction: moveAction];
 }
```

**MySubclass.h**

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface MySubclass : SKSpriteNode

-(MySubclass *) initWithImage: (NSString *) image

@end
```

**MySubclass.m**

```
@implementation MySubclass

-(MySubclass *) initWithImage: (NSString *) image
{
    self = [MySubclass spriteNodeWithImageNamed:image];

    self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:self.size];
    self.physicsBody.dynamic = NO; // Doesnt move with physics
    self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = MySubclassCategory; 
    self.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = otherCategory;
    self.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;

    return self;
}

-(void) runAction:(SKAction *)action
{
    [super runAction:action];
    NSLog(@"Running action!");
}

@end
```

Whenever the action is run, it does log the message "Running action!", so I know it is getting to that method, just not executing the actions for some reason?

Please let me know if you need any more code or information!
Thanks.

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with your subclass not calling an `init` (or `initWith...`) method on `super`.

Comment: I used both the [super initWithPicture: @"picture"] and [MySubclass spriteNode..] . Not sure what is the more correct way but they both did the same thing. For a current workaround I am using the userData for the spritenode, which is working well so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied your code and the action runs fine on your MySubclass object.  Hvae you tried running it in the simulator and hardware?  Does the action run in the simulator?  There are SKAction bugs on the iPhone 5s' 64-bit architecture.

Comment: I've only done this using the iPad simulator, but that is good to know. Currently I have adjusted my programming to use the userData of the node (as a dictionary). It did seem like a bug somewhere in spritekit or the simulator, which is why I went a different route. Thanks for the response!